Whats the Azure OpenAI Inference API Version used by AzureOpenAIEmbeddingSkill
I'm reading this doc about Azure OpenAI Embedding skill, but the document doesn't have any info or property to specify the Azure OpenAI Embedding Inference API (/deployments/{deployment-id}/embeddings) api-version header details. So the question is, which API version will it use?
One can find the available API Versions from
https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/tree/main/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/AzureOpenAI/inference
Ideally, I thought there should be an OpenAI API Property that I can use to pass the api version, too, along with the modelname, deploymentname and azure openai instancename

As of now, there isn’t an explicit property in the Azure Cognitive Search skillset for setting or overriding the API version for Azure OpenAI. Instead, the skillset automatically uses a default API version that’s stable and compatible with the skill.

@Arko thanks for your comment is there any official documentation for this claim ? I don't find this clarity in any docs

Currently there is no doc to specify an API version, my assumption is that Azure Cognitive Search internally manages the API version and defaults to a stable version compatible with the skillset. If you need confirmation reaching out directly to MS support would be the most reliable way to get an official answer since official doc doesn't clearly state the lack of an API version property in the Azure Cognitive Search skillset for Azure OpenAI skills, nor does it provide clarity on how the API version is managed. This has been a common point of confusion.
